# Best Practice - use Javabean for Insert & Update?

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans, sql-insert

I've been unable to locate information on this.

When developing a Java web app using the MVC approach, the general concept is that JSPs are Views, Servlets are Controllers, and your DB with whatever DAOs are your Model.  (This is what I have duplicated.)

When you want to display information to a user from the DB, your DAO does a SELECT query and converts the recordset into javabeans, which your controller then passes to your JSP, which uses JSTL and EL to convert the javabean information into HTML and so on.  I have seen various examples of this.

However, what are the best practices for doing an insert?  I expect to do server-side validation of a form submission in the Controller, but do you then compile the parameters into a javabean before sending it over to the DAO, or just call an insertion method with a bunch of parameters?  I've been unable to find what the best practice is on this.

Thanks!

Comment: When using an ORM framework, you create objects and persist them through the DAO - otherwise, I would do the same without ORM, but also creating some kind of business object and persisting it at the DAO layer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the exact situation. E.g. if you only want to store a single String, you don't really need an object for it, but in complex systems you will most likely use JPA, hence beans. But it never really hurts to use some ORM library, so we could say it's a better practice to use beans.